# Im stuck with my Python code, could someone take a look?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to teach myself python by reading through "Python for absolute beginners" by Michael Dawson. I am currently working through the challenges in chapter 9, largely to really get a grip on how classes actually interact with each other. I am attempting to write a (very) simple text based adventure game where the user travels between various locations. However the way that I am trying is not doing what I want it to. Here is the code:

*Disclaimer - I am well aware this probably looks like garbage, I don't entirely understand what I've written myself and its aim is just to give me an understanding of class interactions.

```
# classes module for my basic adventure game
import random

# the locations that the player will travel to 
class Location(object):
    """Locations that the adventurer can travel to"""
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

class Location_list(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.locations = []

    def __str__ (self):
        if self.locations:
            rep = ""
            for location in self.locations:
                rep += str(location)
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep

    def clear(self):
        self.locations = []

    def add(self, location):
        self.locations.append(location)

    def rand_location(self):
        x = random.choice(self.locations)
        print("You step out of the magical portal, it has taken you to", x, "!")


# The player
class Adventurer(object):
    """An adventurer who travels to different locations within a mystical world"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def travel(self):
        Location_list.rand_location
        print("You step into the magic portal")


loc1 = Location("London", "The capital of the UK")
loc2 = Location("Paris", "The capital city of France")
loc3 = Location("Berlin", "The capital city of Germany")
location_list = Location_list



player = Adventurer(input("What is your name traveller?"))

question = input("do you want to travel now?")

if question == "yes":
                player.travel()
else: print("No journey for you bellend")

input("press enter to exit")
```

This is my code so far. Effectively what I wanted to do was have a class of locations and a class that created a list of those locations. I would then have a method on the location class that called a method on the location list class to return a random location from the list. As far as I can tell the problem i'm having is that the list isn't actually being created. The code i used for this i actually stole from earlier in the chapter as i thought it would do what i wanted it to do - code in question:

```
class Location_list(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.locations = []

        def __str__ (self):
            if self.locations:
                rep = ""
                for location in self.locations:
                    rep += str(location)
```

The problem is that i dont actually get anything back from calling the players travel method beyond calling the print parts of it.

So firstly could someone please help me sort out what i've already got so that that the location list actually creates a list of location objects, and then the method randomly selects from this list

And secondly, if my code is, as i suspect, barking up the completely wrong tree. Could someone show me a way of creating a class that is a list of other objects.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for joining Stack Overflow! This is a great place to get questions like yours answered, but you have to learn to ask them better. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for general guidance. Your description and code is long, but you don't even say what the problem is. Do you get an error message? Did you expect something to be printed but something else gets printed? Tell us the problem! On the other hand I don't think I need to know what inspired you to learn programming to answer the question :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't describe your problem, but mention you suspect some list not getting created. Indeed you have a line like this:

```
location_list = Location_list
```

This line has a mistake! You should change it to:

```
location_list = Location_list()
```

The second version creates an instance of the `Location_list` class and assigns it to a variable. This is what you want. On the other hand the first version gives another name to the `Location_list` class. So then you could say `location_list()` to create an instance of the same class. But that is not what you want.

I didn't read through the whole code, just looked at uses of this list, but here's another mistake:

```
def travel(self):
    Location_list.rand_location
    print("You step into the magic portal")
```

`Location_list` is a class. `Location_list.rand_location` is an unbound method of this class. In that line you just refer to this method, but you don't even call it. It's like writing `15` on a line. Valid code, but doesn't do anything.

Instead you want to refer to an instance of the class. If you've fixed the first mistake you can write `location_list`. (note the lowercase `l` instead of `L`.) And you want to *call* the `rand_location` method. So you need to write:

```
def travel(self):
    location_list.rand_location()
    print("You step into the magic portal")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to properly instantiate Location_list with `location_list = Location_list()` Then you have to add the location instances to your location_list instance. So after that
add

```
location_list.add(loc1)
location_list.add(loc2)
location_list.add(loc3)
```

Also to print these locations you should add a `__str__` method to your Location class else str(location) won't give you the name of the location:

```
    def __str__ (self):
        if self.name:
            return str(self.name)
```